# Can't load mouse cursor texture on C#/Unity

Tags: c#, nullreferenceexception, texture2d, mouse-cursor

```
public class Cursor : MonoBehaviour 
{ 
     public Texture2D cursor; 
     public int cursorSizeX = 16; // default 
     public int cursorSizeY = 16; // default 

// Use this for initialization 
void Start () 
{ 
     Object temp = Resources.Load("Textures/CR_Cursor (Custom)"); 

     if (temp == null) 
     Debug.Log("Load Object Fail"); 

     cursor = (Texture2D)Resources.Load("Textures/CR_Cursor (Custom)"); 

     if (cursor == null) 
     Debug.Log("Load Cursor Fail"); 

     Screen.showCursor = false; 
} 

// Update is called once per frame 
void Update () 
{ 
     GUI.DrawTexture(new Rect(Event.current.mousePosition.x - cursorSizeX / 2,      Event.current.mousePosition.y - cursorSizeY / 2, cursorSizeX, cursorSizeY), cursor); 
}
```

no matter where I instantiate the cursor im sill getting NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object 
Cursor.Update (), what I am missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should put this line

```
GUI.DrawTexture(new Rect(Event.current.mousePosition.x - cursorSizeX / 2,      Event.current.mousePosition.y - cursorSizeY / 2, cursorSizeX, cursorSizeY), cursor);
```

inside of OnGUI() and not in Update

```
void OnGUI(){

GUI.DrawTexture(new Rect(Event.current.mousePosition.x - cursorSizeX / 2,      Event.current.mousePosition.y - cursorSizeY / 2, cursorSizeX, cursorSizeY), cursor); 

}
```

here is a chart concerning the lifecycle of script

[image: Scripting Lifecycle]

Comment: That did it. Even so I see the mouse blinking sometimes, specially at the beginning of the scene. Any way to avoid it? I should use no Update() function then? If I did use one, OnGUI would be executed peviously or later than Update?

Comment: i put up a script lifecycle chart and im pretty sure you can set the graphic for the mouse cursor in player setting somewhere

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that you have change the texture properties as following in Inspector window,

- Texture Type: Cursor
- Alpha Is Transparent: True
- Read/Write: True
- Generate Mip Maps: False

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to create a custom cursor using Unity's GUI.DrawTexture method. The NullReferenceException you're encountering usually indicates that you're trying to access a member of an object that is currently null.

The use of Event.current within the Update method is likely causing problems. Event.current is generally used in GUI event handling, and it might not be set properly in the Update method. Instead, you could use Input.mousePosition:

```
    void Update()
{
    Vector3 mousePosition = Input.mousePosition;
    GUI.DrawTexture(new Rect(mousePosition.x - cursorSizeX / 2, mousePosition.y - cursorSizeY / 2, cursorSizeX, cursorSizeY), cursor);
}
```